# dialog box causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, dialog, memory-leaks

This is the issue, I have a dialog box that only appears the first time a user installs my app. After testing with my own device I see that simply doing nothing after the box pops up causes the app to crash. My intention is to have this dialog box be the first thing that the user sees after installing the app. It does appear, but causes the app to crash if the user does not press a button within about 3 seconds. However, if I relaunch the app after the crash then the box is displayed forever until the user presses a button which is my intended goal for the box.

Here is the logcat:

```
12-13 15:25:28.625: ERROR/WindowManager(15315): Activity com.nick.simplequiz.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41506ff0 V.E..... R....... 0,0-684,679} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.nick.simplequiz.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41506ff0 V.E..... R....... 0,0-684,679} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:458)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:216)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is the line where the error happens according to the logcat:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

What could be causing this to happen?

This is the code, inside the `onCreate` method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("...."); //Set the title of the box
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("....");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel(); //when they click dismiss we will dismiss the box
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = sp.edit();
            edit2.putInt("SHOW", 1);
            edit2.commit();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            .......
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); //create the box
    alertDialog.show(); //*************error happens here
```

Comment: When you say doing nothing, is it crashing when device goes to sleep/resumes? Is there some sort of time component here?

Comment: Post the code where is alertDialog.show();

Comment: after waiting 3 seconds after the app opens it crashes

Comment: Check the answer i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity. You need to call the `dismiss()` method on the dialog in the `onPause()` of the activity to solve the problem

Comment: I am slightly confused because this dialog box is intended to be the first thing that pops up on top of the main activity after the app is installed. It should be as soon as the activity is started that the dialog box appears. Is the main activity somehow paused while the dialog box is up?

Comment: the error says that the activity closed but the popup remained. Try adding dialog.dismiss in the onPause method as i suggested. The activity is killed by the time you show the popup. Hence the error

Comment: It ended up being a different issue. In my onPause method I for some reason had killed the main activity, so the dialog box paused the activity and caused the crash.

Comment: there you go. remove that thing from the onPause and it should work. And accept and upvote if you found the answer helpful. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you try to add window to non existing reference or already killed reference. leaked window error refers that you have killed the activity from which this pop up was shown but pop up is still visible on the device. you will have to remove the pop up window before killing the activity.